# in ionic when i minimize the app and open again reload the alway first page

Tags: ionic-framework

Hello i am app developer using ionic framework, in this problem  when copy the text from another app and go back to the my app , App is reload from the main screen. but minimize before open in our app is different screen.

so please help us

Comment: Are you listening to some resume event in app? otherwise it is impossible. may be you are closing app instead of minimizing.

Answer (score 1):

Add some action. For example

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (){
    if($ionicHistory.currentStateName() === 'home' || $ionicHistory.currentStateName() === 'login'){
        $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: 'Exit',
            template: 'Are you sure?'
        }).then(function(option){
            if(option === true){
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            } else {
                console.log('Do nothing');
            }
        });
    } else {
        navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
}, 100);
```

Instead of home, login you can mention the state name that you are there at the time of copy action